# How to access class fields of a class that I only know it by its string name?

Tags: java, reflection, class, field, classloader

For instance, I have a class called "My_Class_X123.java" like this :

```
public class My_Class_X123    // This file was generated by a java program
{
  static String ABC[]={"1","2",...};
  int XYZ=0;
}
```

When I wrote my program I didn't know there would be a class by this name, but at run time I found out a class by the name of "My_Class_X123.java" exists and I want to use its fields such as ABC and XYZ above, how to get those values ?

---

OK, I got the answer, it's something like this :

```
  try
  {
    Class myClass=Class.forName("My_Class_X123");
    Field fields[]=myClass.getDeclaredFields();
    String New_ABC[]=String[].class.cast(fields[0].get(String[].class));
  }
  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Wouldn't it be nice to have some sample code like this in the java doc, to show user how to do it !

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Reflection](http://vivin.net/2009/12/04/jstl-instanceof-and-hasproperty/). A while back I [wrote](http://vivin.net/2009/12/04/jstl-instanceof-and-hasproperty/) some JSTL tag utilities that does this sort of thing. One function checks to see if a class is an instance of a passed-in string (`instanceof` basically). The other checks to see whether a class has a specified property (`hasProperty`). The following code snippet should help:

```
//Checks to see if Object 'o' is an instance of the class in the string "className"
public static boolean instanceOf(Object o, String className) {
    boolean returnValue;

    try {
        returnValue = Class.forName(className).isInstance(o);
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        returnValue = false;
    }

    return returnValue;
}

//Checks to see if Object 'o' has a property specified in "propertyName"
public static boolean hasProperty(Object o, String propertyName) {
    boolean methodFound = false;
    int i = 0;

    Class myClass = o.getClass();
    String methodName = "get" + propertyName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + propertyName.substring(1);
    Method[] methods = myClass.getMethods();

    while(i < methods.length && !methodFound) {
        methodFound = methods[i].getName().compareTo(methodName) == 0;
        i++;
    }

    return methodFound;
}
```

Pay particular attention to the `Class.forName` method in the first method (which loads and initializes a class) and `getMethods()` method in the second function, which returns all methods defined for a class.

What you probably want is `Class.forName` which also initializes the class. After that you can use `newInstance` to get a new instance of that class (if you need one). To access the fields, you need to use the `Method` objects that you got from `getMethod()`. Use the `invoke` method on those objects. If those methods are getter methods, then you now have access to the field you want.

**EDIT**

After looking at the code in your question, I realized that you need getters and setters for those attributes. So assuming you have `getABC` and `getXYZ` defined, here is a somewhat contrived example:

```
public Object reflectionDemo(String className, String getter) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {

   Object fieldValue;
   Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
   Object myClassInstance = myClass.newInstance(); //to get an instance of the class       

   if(myClassInstance instanceof My_Class_X123) {       
      //null because we are not specifying the kind of arguments that class takes
      Method getterMethod = myClass.getMethod(getter, null); 
      //null because the method takes no arguments
      //Also in the scenario that the method is static one, it is not necessary to pass in an instance, so in that case, the first parameter can be null.
      fieldValue = getterMethod.invoke(myClassInstance, null);
   } 

   return fieldValue;
}
```

The above approach is more generic. If you only want the fields, then you can use the method James described:

```
myClass = null;
try {
  myClass = Class.forName(className);
  Field[] fields = myClass.getDeclaredFields();

  for(Field field : fields) {
    //do whatever with the field. Look at the API reference at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html    
  }
}

catch(Exception e) {
  //handle exception
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the "o" object first ?

Comment: At programming time I don't know the name of the class, so this line won't work : "if(myClassInstance instanceof My_Class_X123)"

Comment: Oops, my bad. All you can do in that case, really, is take out the `instanceof` and try and get the Method with the specified name anyway. This will throw a `NoSuchMethodException` if the method does not exist, so you need a `try...catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.lang.reflect. First use ClassLoader to get a Class for the class, then you can call newInstance to get an object, then you can use the reflection interfaces to get the fields.

A comprehensive tutorial live [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the class fields you don't even need to create an instance, just as long as you use reflection to get the Class you can use `getDeclaredFields()` method to get the name of the fields and their values, e.g.

```
Class myClass = null;

try {
    myClass = Class.forName("package.ClassName");
    Field[] fields = myClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
         System.out.println("Field type is: " + field.getType());
         System.out.println("Field name is: " + field.getName());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Ooh, nice! Somehow that slipped by me :) I have a question though, why do you have the code that gets the declared field inside your catch block? Wouldn't `myClass` be `null`?

Comment: I do need to use the values in the fields, not just their names.

Comment: Alright, so how do I get the values "1","2" ... from my sample code's ABC[] ?

Comment: Frank, look at the Java API documentation for the Field object.

Comment: Yes I have, but still can't figure out how, it'll be nice if it has sample usages in the doc, what I can think of now is something like this :
if (field.getName().equals("ABC"))
{
  String ABC_New[]=(String[])field;
  ... then use ABC_New[] ...
}

But it won't work, what's the correct way to do it ?